# Wordpress 3.9 doesn't automatically generate <p> and <br> tag by default

Tags: wordpress

I use WP 3.9 with clean install (not upgrade). And using about two plugins that support 3.9 too (although this is not related to plugin)

When *Heading1*, *Heading2*, etc.. are selected it generates `<h1>`, `<h2>` tag correctly. But when *Paragraph* is selected, it doesn't generate `<p>` tag. Even when the text was entered, it generates `&nbsp;`. (Why not `<br>` or `<p>` tag?)

I was reading **editor.js** when asking this question. Looking for how to make the editor to automatically generates `<p>` and `<br>` tag. If anyone want to share the answer here, it would help.

Thanks lots :)

Comment: Are you sure about your plugins, have you deactivated them. Another issue might be your theme. Search for something like `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` or 
`remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );` What happens when you switch to the default themes?